# Regex to find and replace a string between two strings? Detailed description in the comment

Tags: regex, replace, wikipedia

I am a wikipedia editor, and I have **zero experience with regex** I use wikipedia's auto wiki browser to do repetitive tasks. I often need to remove spam links from articles. Currently there is a website link which has been used in around 1500 articles. It needs to be removed from all the articles.

Wikipedia has many templates/methods for adding references in the article. But if I see one working regex, I can then update it for other methods as well. One of the referencing style is:

`<ref name="pakrail.com">{{Cite web |url=http://www.pakrail.com/ybook2.pdf |title=PRINCIPAL STATISTICS |access-date=18 November 2016 |archive-url=https://web.archive.org/web/20170209175303/http://www.pakrail.com/ybook2.pdf |archive-date=9 February 2017 |url-status=dead |df=dmy-all }}</ref>`

In this case, I want to find instance of `www.pakrail.com` between `<ref` and `/ref>` tags, and then delete whatever is inside *that particular ref tags*. In short, it will remove the reference. But it shouldn't delete the other valid websites/reference inside other ref tags.

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead to keep the match within the tag:

```
<ref ((?!/ref>).)*www.pakrail.com((?!/ref>).)*/ref>
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/3eskZpVFwFjqKZ).

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked perfectly on wikipedia.